# Form data empty and csrf token invalid in Symfony 6.2

Tags: forms, symfony-forms, symfony6

I am building a Signup form in Symfony 6.2. I am building it the same way as I had built it in Symfony 2, 3 and 4 versions. But it's not working and when submitted form data is empty. This is how the Type and Model for the form looks like.

```
class SignupType extends AbstractType
{
 public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
    $builder->add('firstName', TextType::class, [
        'required' => true,
    ]);

    $builder->add('lastName', TextType::class, [
        'required' => true,
    ]);

    $builder->add('email', TextType::class, [
        'required' => true,
    ]);

    $builder->add('password', PasswordType::class, [
        'required' => true,
    ]);

    $builder->add('confirmPassword', PasswordType::class, [
        'required' => true,
    ]);
}

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'data_class' => SignupModel::class
    ]);
}
```

}

```
   class SignupModel
   {
 /**
 * @Assert\NotNull(message="First name is required.")
 * @var string
 */
private string $firstName;

/**
 * @Assert\NotNull(message="Last name is required.")
 * @var string
 */
private string $lastName;

/**
 * @Assert\NotNull(message="Please enter a valid email address.")
 * @var string
 */
private string $email;

/**
 * @Assert\NotNull(message="Password is required")
 * @var string
 */
private string $password;

/**
 * @Assert\NotNull(message="Confirm password is required")
 * @var string
 */
private string $confirmPassword;

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getFirstName(): string
{
    return $this->firstName;
}

/**
 * @param string $firstName
 */
public function setFirstName(string $firstName): void
{
    $this->firstName = $firstName;
}

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getLastName(): string
{
    return $this->lastName;
}

/**
 * @param string $lastName
 */
public function setLastName(string $lastName): void
{
    $this->lastName = $lastName;
}

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getEmail(): string
{
    return $this->email;
}

/**
 * @param string $email
 */
public function setEmail(string $email): void
{
    $this->email = $email;
}

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getPassword(): string
{
    return $this->password;
}

/**
 * @param string $password
 */
public function setPassword(string $password): void
{
    $this->password = $password;
}

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getConfirmPassword(): string
{
    return $this->confirmPassword;
}

/**
 * @param string $confirmPassword
 */
public function setConfirmPassword(string $confirmPassword): void
{
    $this->confirmPassword = $confirmPassword;
}}
```

Controller side looks like this:

```
        $form = $this->createForm(SignupType::class, new SignupModel());

    if ($request->getMethod() !== Request::METHOD_POST) {
        return $this->render("signup.html.twig", [
            'signupForm' => $form->createView()
        ]);
    }

    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if (!$form->isValid() && $form->getErrors()->count()) {
        $this->addFlash('danger', (string)$form->getErrors());

        return $this->redirectToRoute("signup");
    }

    dump($form->getData()); die;
```

In twig it looks like this:

```
                        <form class="js-validate needs-validation" action="{{ path('signup') }}" method="post">
                        <div class="mb-5">
                            <h3 class="card-title">Signup</h3>
                        </div>

 {#
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <div class="mb-4">
                               {{ form_row(signupForm.firstName) }}
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <div class="mb-4">
                                    {{ form_row(signupForm.lastName) }}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="mb-4">
                            {{ form_row(signupForm.email) }}
                        </div>

                        <div class="mb-4">
                            <div class="input-group-merge">
                                {{ form_row(signupForm.password) }}
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="mb-4">
                            {{ form_row(signupForm.confirmPassword) }}
                        </div>
```

#}

```
                        {#<input type="hidden" id="signup__token" name="signup[_token]" value="{{ csrf_token('authenticate') }}">#}

                        {{ form_rest(signupForm) }}

                        {#{% include "shared/_captcha.html.twig" %}#}
                        {#<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token('authenticate') }}" />#}


                        <div class="form-check mb-4">
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="termsCheckbox">I accept the <a href="#">Terms and Conditions</a></label>
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="termsCheckbox" required>
                        </div>

                        {% if error is defined %}
                            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                                {{ error.messageKey|trans(error.messageData, 'security') }}
                            </div>
                        {% endif %}

                        <div class="d-grid gap-4">
                            <button name="signup" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Signup</button>

                            <div class="mb-4">
                                <p class="card-text text-muted">
                                   Already have an account?
                                    <a class="link" href="{{ path('login') }}">Login</a>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    {#{{ form_end(signupForm) }}#}
                    </form>
```

CSRF token error was also generated but I disabled it for the time being. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issues after spending many hours. If you render all the fields using `form_widget` or `form_row` then Symfony is happy and will not throw any csrf related error and data will also be populated.

But if you render any field by simple HTML, even if you give it the same name and id which `form_row` or `form_widget` will assign, somehow Symfony considers it as been modified and thus form data will not be populated when submitted and also csrf error will be generated.

In my case I was rendering them using HTML and also I had not added the Submit button the FormtType, that's why I was getting csrf error and data was not present when form was submitted.

I hope someone might find it helpful.